# get_current_blog_id returns 1 in multisite setting

Tags: multisite, blog-id

I am encountering rather a weirdo situation here.

I am currently on a multisite and created a site. This site has a blog id of 3. However, whenever I call get_current_blog_id() it returns 1 (which is obviously a network id).

I do not know why but there was definitely a change with the domain.

example)
used to be
random.com/the_mania
now it is
random.com/community/the_mania

I am running IIS by the way. What would be the cause for this?

Comment: Try seeing what [get_blog_details()](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_details) gives you…

Comment: Can you [update your question ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/185111/edit) to include some of the context around your `get_current_blog_id()` call, please?

Comment: @WilliamTurrell I'm getting this value too. When I call get_blog_details() it returns information about the root network site. Site ID is "1" and site URL is the default network blog URL. The site I'm working with is site 93. I log in through the network site URL if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4):

`get_current_blog_id()` uses the global variable `$blog_id` as noted at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id. When I've seen this problem before it's because I'm declaring `$blog_id` in my PHP code which is overwriting the WordPress global variable that provides the ID of the subsite.

Change the variable name of `$blog_id` and hopefully the function will start returning the correct site ID.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have saved my time. In my case it was the strange index equals 256. Sometimes how WP works in the core is really sad: global variables, etc.